# Вывод данных в ReclerView Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Есть база данных Firebase с такой структурой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно вывести вывести в RecyclerView значения из "comment"?

Answer (score 1):

Вятягиваете весь список комментарией в список объектов User(или что у вас за id скрыто). Далее передаете список этих объектов на вход адаптера recyclerView. Во Viewhilder непосредственно обращаетесь к User.comment.

Обект User должен быть следующего типа со строгим соблюдением названий переменных как в базе и соотвествующими геттерами. Если что, я могу вас из дома в комментарии добавить пример такого проекта.

Comment: Спасибо, но как мне объявить путь до значения "comment" ведь там уникальный идентификатор запушенной записи? `mDatabase.child("Comments").chilld(????)`.

Comment: вы работает через оффицициальный апи? Лично я использовал rx-java библиотеку для работа с firebase. Не думаю, что ради одного запроса стоит менять готовую архитектуру)) Ищет способ вытянуть целый список или map.